# Pymongo - store PDF data as Binary

Tags: python, mongodb, binary, pymongo

I am working on a project where I want to store PDF data within a Mongo collection. I realize this has been asked around the community, but I am struggling with the result. My code is able to insert a document into the collection, but stalls because it enters a blank binary object.

```
import base64, os
import pymongo
import bson
from pathlib import Path

file_used = 'sample.pdf'
my_file = Path(file_used)
if my_file.is_file():
    print("File Exists") #prints successfully

with open(file_used, 'rb') as fout:
    string = base64.b64encode(fout.read())
    collection.insert_one({"filename":file_used,"pdf_data":string})
```

Document in MDB Compass:

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"60583bfdffea362641c50944"}, 
    "filename":"sample.pdf", 
    "pdf_data":{"$binary":"","$type":"0"}
}
```

My python file is also located in the same directory as my sample PDF file.
Execution: `python3 test.py`

How can I debug my code further? Thank you in advance for your help?

Comment: What is the value of the variable `collection` - in the statement `collection.insert_one({ ...` ?

Comment: @prasad_ it was db.coll. The document successfully posted to Mongo. It was PDF file that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something was wrong with the PDF file. It worked once I used another PDF file as my test case.